# How can I proxy requests to a specific IP to a different IP on OS X?

Tags: iptables, mac-osx, proxy, routing, route

On OS X how can I setup a route so that when I make a request to 10.0.0.1 it is redirected to localhost? Right now I can do `curl localhost:3000` and get back a blob of HTML from my running node web server. I'd like to be able to do `curl 10.0.0.1:3000` and have that redirected to localhost. The 10.0.0.1 IP is arbitrary, just used for this example :)